# URL redirect for changed url structure

Tags: uri

I changed my Drupal 6 website tag structure and got a new URL however old URLs are indexed in Google and are generating 404 errors.

My old URLs are

```
www.mydomain.com/topics/12345/widget
www.mydomain.com/topics/5783/widget2
```

numeral - 12345 in this URL was tag no in the database

new URL structure is

```
www.mydomain.com/topics/widget
www.mydomain.com/topics/widget2
```

Now I wish to create a redirect so that

```
mydomain.com/topics/12345/widget
```

goes to

```
www.mydomain.com/topics/widget
```

and remove the random numeral nos in URL.. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Path Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module. Module page says -

> This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another
>   path or an external URL, using any HTTP redirect status.

As I see you are talking about taxonomy terms, so alternatively you can use [Taxonomy Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_redirect).

> This module allows the administrator to change the destination of
>   Taxonomy Term links.
>
> - The module can now handle redirections at the term level.
> - You can specify a replacement character for spaces and + characters.
> - You can specify a list of characters or strings to remove from the path
> - You can enter php code that will create your path at runtime (In 5.x-1.3, variables for term ID ($tid) and term name ($tname) are available to use in your php code).

Comment: other than this is there any htaccess redirect also possible?

Comment: You can look into documentation for .htaccess redirect at https://drupal.org/node/38960

Comment: can u give specific example as what to do as i am a newbie and cant figure out

Comment: @Deepblue You can through the documentation of https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect. It's pretty much self-explanatory..